# Highcharts Point marker

Tags: highcharts

When you hover on any point in highcharts graphs. The point is highlighted(zoomed). Is there a way to remove this effect and show the points as it is (like without hover) and the tooltip be shown?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.enabled